# Visual Studio 2013 Performance and Diagnostics for profiling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am working in a desktop application and I would like to measure the performance of the file loading scalability when user opens up a file.

I am developing using Visual Studio 2013, so the obvious choice is to use the Performance and Diagnostics - Performance Wizard - Instrumentation to measure the time taken for file loading.

However, I found out that the profiler tool will launch the application and starts collecting data till I click on the stop profiling button. What I need is just the file loading part. Is there a way to start the profiling data collection 
just before user clicks on file open dialog ? and not from the beginning of the application ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you uncheck "Launch profiling after wizard finishes" on the last page of the Performance Wizard, you will then have a session created in the Performance Explorer. You can then use "Actions -> Start with Profiling Paused" to launch the application without profiling. Then right before you click the file open dialog, click "Resume profiling" in the .vsp document window.

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck **Launch profiling after wizard finishes** and start profiling when you need.